# Asignacion de valores a parametros en ISO 8583 con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

soy nuevo en la creacion de sockets y tramas para transacciones de tarjetas virtuales o recargas, actualmente estoy trabajando con python y su libreria del iso 8583 , por lo cual estoy viendo en la necesidad de ver como puedo asignarle los parametros la libreria correctamente, el ejemplo es este:

```
iso.setBit(3, 990000)  # PROCCESING CODE
iso.setBit(11, 123612)  # STAN
iso.setBit(12, 173645)  # TIME
iso.setBit(13, 1515)  # DATE
```

inicializo un valor  que por defecto  en mi metodo el primero es el codigo de referencia del parametro del iso, y el segundo es su valor, el cual en algunos casos como el PROCESSING CODE y el STAN, ya lo tengo mapeado por el tipo de transacion , pero el DATE y el TIME, los puse aleatoriamente, y quisiera saber como definirlos realmente, otro ejemplo:

```
iso.setBit(41, '29110001')  # TERMINAL ID
```

necesito adicionalmente a ello el terminal id  el cual la documentacion me dice que tengo que definirlo en ascii, pero como lo calcularia , saber si es el ip de la maquina o la ip publica que necesito enviar y como volverla a ascii, por favor necesito sus aportes y su apoyo gracias.